# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<imageObject>?' | How to input Array of Objects in Model firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, object, exception

I have been trying to actually get the data from firebase
So the actual data is :
[image]

**How to get the imageUrl ?**

My Try is :

```
class ProductModel {
  String? name;
  String? price;
  String? discountPrice;
  String? discountRate;
  String? category;
  String? description;
  List<imageObject>? image;

  ProductModel(
      {required this.name,
      required this.price,
      this.category,
      this.description,
      this.discountPrice,
      this.discountRate,
      this.image});

  ProductModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    
    name = data['name'];
    // image = data['imageUrls'][0]['url']; // To get single image i do this
    image = data['imageUrls']; // but this is not working 
    category = data['category'];
    description = data['Description'];
    price = data['price'];
    discountPrice = data['discountPrice'];
    discountRate = data['discountRate'];
  }
}

class imageObject {
  final String public_id;
  final String url;

  imageObject({
    required this.public_id,
    required this.url,
  });
}
```

It gives exception :`Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<imageObject>?'`

And to access the first image i am doing,

```
product.image![0].url,
```

where product is of type ProductModel

But this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deserialize the *imageObject* json data as well. For that you need to add the *factory imageObject.fromJson()* constructor to your *imageObject* class just like you did for the ProductModel class.

Here's the code you need:

```
  class ProductModel {
  String? name;
  String? price;
  String? discountPrice;
  String? discountRate;
  String? category;
  String? description;
  List<imageObject>? image;

  ProductModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
    this.category,
    this.description,
    this.discountPrice,
    this.discountRate,
    this.image,
  });

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => ProductModel(
        name: jsonData['name'] as String?,
        price: jsonData['price'] as String?,
        category: jsonData['category'] as String?,
        description: jsonData['Description'] as String?,
        discountPrice: jsonData['discountPrice'] as String?,
        discountRate: jsonData['discountRate'] as String?,
        
        //Have a good look here to understand how nested list of maps are deserialized

        image: (jsonData['imageUrls'] as List<dynamic>?)
            ?.map((e) => imageObject.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList(),
      );
}

class imageObject {
  final String public_id;
  final String url;

  imageObject({
    required this.public_id,
    required this.url,
  });

  factory imageObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => imageObject(
        public_id: jsonData['public_id'] as String,
        url: jsonData['url'] as String,
      );
}
```

What we did here is, take the data from imageUrls key as a List and map every individual element thru the json constructor of the imageObject method.

Comment: Thank you bro, Is there any where the detailed explanation  of this ? I would love to understand this thoroughly ,I am not understanding this code

Comment: Here's an article that helped me immensely https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51 Also there is a package called json_serializable which helps you automatically generate code for parsing objects to and from json. You might wanna take a look at that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to map the recived list to an `imageObject`s list.

1. Create a fromMap constructor for your `imageObject` class

```
class imageObject {
  final String public_id;
  final String url;

  imageObject({
    required this.public_id,
    required this.url,
  });
  imageObject.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => imageObject(public_id = map['public_id'], url = map['url'] );
}
```

2. Use it something like the following:

```dart
 ProductModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    
    name = data['name'];
    image = data['imageUrls'].map((map) => imageObject.fromMap(map) ); 
    category = data['category'];
    description = data['Description'];
    price = data['price'];
    discountPrice = data['discountPrice'];
    discountRate = data['discountRate'];
  }
```

You may need to do add some casting or do some modifications to the previous code make it work, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but It gives this error bro , Unhandled Exception: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ImageObject>?'